# Indexing 3d matrix with 2d Matrix plus vector

Tags: matlab, indexing, 3d

I have a m * n * k Matrix called M which I want to index to get the mean of some Data.

I have a logical m * n matrix called EZG and want to apply this on every of the k-th dimension from 1:(end-1) (call this vector V).

Any chance to write it without a loop like this:

```
M=rand(3,3,3)
EZG=logical([1,1,1;0,1,0;0,0,1])
V=1:size(M,3)-1

mean(mean(M(EZG,V)1),2)
```

Result should be a onedimensional vector of the length of V.
Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you give a numeric exaple?

Comment: I did add one example.

Comment: No you didn't. I meant specifying the input _and output_, with _specific values_. BTW I downvoted because that makes the question low-quality in my opinion (as I can't understand exactly what is being asked). If you edit I will happily remove my downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
M=rand(3,3,3);
EZG=logical([1,1,1;0,1,0;0,0,1]);
% repeat EZG K-1 times, and add zeros to the Kth slice
V=cat(3,repmat(EZG,1,1,size(M,3)-1),false(size(M,1),size(M,2)));
% logical index and mean
m=mean(M(V));
```